# Multiple unique ways of executing a simple query (ORACLE)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have to come up with 5 different ways (unique execution plans) to process the following query.

**Find the items that are delivered by all suppliers.**

My database holds the following tables:

**QSPL** – it holds a list of supplier names

- SPLNO (number)
- SPLNAME (varchar)

**QDEL**– it holds delivery items, suppliers, and departments

- DELNO (number)
- DELQTY (number)
- ITEMNAME (varchar)
- DEPTNAME (varchar)
- SPLNO (number)

**QITEM** – it holds list of items

- ITEMNAME (varchar)
- ITEMTYPE (varchar)
- ITEMCOLOR (varchar)

I was able to successfully come up with the following four unique queries.

**1.**

```
select itemname --, etc.
from qitem
where itemname not in
(select itemname
from qitem, qspl
where (char(splno)+itemname) not in
(select char(splno)+itemname
from qdel));
```

**2.**

```
select itemname --,etc.
from qitem
where not exists
    (select *
    from qspl
    where not exists
        (select *
from qdel
where qdel.itemname = qitem.itemname
and Qdel.splno = qspl.splno));
```

**3.**

```
select a.itemname --, etc
from qitem a join qdel b on a.itemname = b.itemname
group by a.itemname
having count (distinct splno) = (select count(*) from qspl);
```

**4.**

```
select itemname
from qdel
group by itemname
having count (distinct splno) = (select count(*) from qspl);
```

I have no idea what to do for a 5th unique query.
Does anyone have a clue?

I tried to put this question in the best possible context with significant detail, feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do you get partial credit for the 4?

Comment: @tbone not sure, my professor is pretty strict

Comment: In query #1: `char(splno)+itemname` is invalid in Oracle. The string concatenation operator in Oracle and standard SQL is `||`. But it's better to us `where (splno, itemname) not in
(select splno, itemname from qdel)` Concatenating the numbers can yield wrong results, because `(1,23)` and `(12,3)` will be treated as the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some SQL 86 syntax:

```
select a.itemname --, etc
from qitem a, qdel b 
where a.itemname = b.itemname
group by a.itemname
having count (distinct splno) = (select count(*) from qspl);
```

Or an outer join

```
select a.itemname --, etc
from qspl s, qdel b 
WHERE s.splno (+)= b.splno
group by s.splno
having count (distinct b.splno) = (select count(*) from qspl);
```

Comment: Please don't use the (propietary)  `(+)` operator. Oracle recommends to not use it any more.

Comment: Your first suggestion executed perfectly with a cost of 4. Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed. I would up vote it but I do not have enough rep.

Comment: @BobJones I am pretty sure that you can always upvote answers to your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is another unique way (which I'm sure it's horribly inefficient):

```
select distinct splname
from (
  select qi.itemname, 
         qs.splname,
         count(distinct qi.itemname) over () as total_items,
         count(distinct qd.itemname) over (partition by qd.splno) as items_per_supp
  from qitem qi
    left join qdel qd on qi.itemname = qd.itemname
    left join qspl qs on qs.splno = qd.splno
) t
where total_items = items_per_supp
```

Or a variant of your #3 which will probably use a different execution plan:

```
with supplier_items as (
  select splno, count(*) item_count
  from qdel 
  group by splno
)
select splname
from qspl qs
  join supplier_items si on qs.splno = si.splno
where si.item_count = (select count(*) from qitem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I will be obtuse: Check out the Oracle MINUS operator.